# Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch - node Bot Project

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, error-handling

My Bot program is smoothly running in locally , using
`node bot.js` 
( not using any port or loop for catch received messages, because it's done by plugin )

when i deploy this project in Heroku , it's working like a one min and auto crashed with

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiOov.png)

How to solve this , Help me to solve this .

i tried many ways and get same error ,

here my current connection make and bot.js code in bot -

```
`const makeWASocket = require("@whiskeysockets/baileys").default;
const { DisconnectReason, useMultiFileAuthState, qr, MessageType, MessageOptions, Mimetype } = require("@whiskeysockets/baileys");
const axios = require('axios');
const weather = require('./plugins/weather');
const generateImageAndSend = require("./plugins/imagecreate");
const search = require('./plugins/ytSearch');
const song = require('./plugins/songDl');
const mp4 = require('./plugins/mp4dl');
const fs = require('fs');
const short = require("./shorts");

async function connectionLogic() {
  const { state, saveCreds } = await useMultiFileAuthState("auth_info_baileys");

  // Declare the sock variable
  const sock = makeWASocket({

    auth: state,
    printQRInTerminal: true,
  });

  sock.ev.on("connection.update", async (update) => {
    const { connection, lastDisconnect } = update || {};
    if (qr) {
      console.log(qr);
    }
    if (connection === "close") {
      const shouldReconnect =
        lastDisconnect?.error?.output?.statusCode !== DisconnectReason.loggedOut;
      if (shouldReconnect) {
        connectionLogic();
      }
    }
  });

  // Listen for messages
  const lang = require('./lang.json');

  sock.ev.on("messages.upsert", async ({ messages }) => {}

  sock.ev.on("creds.update", saveCreds);
}

// Run the bot
connectionLogic();
```

`

need a help